# C# Whenever a row is added to the database the program warns

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am developing a project in C#/SQL and I am a trainee in a company, here they told me to do, that when a new row is added to the database, the C# program put a messagebox saying "Alert!".

My tutor said to make a row.count and every time that count a new row the program give the alert, but I don't know how to pass this obstacle. Can someone help me?
I had created a label that counted the rows that the table had, and what I was thinking to do was whenever the number of that label increases it's because something was added... But I don't know if it is correct...

```
int count = 0;
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count = bialertaBindingSource.Count;
            label1.Text = count.ToString();

        }
```

I have an arduino that reads the values and automatically passes them to the database, I have a trigger in the database that if the values pass the defined ones, it passes to the "Alerts" table, so what I have to do is when that trigger puts a row in the "Alerts" table, the C# program warns with a message box!

Comment: Way too broad we need lots of specific information to be able to assist.

Comment: Misunderstanting this issue.
You need some kind of event, which fires when some new row added to some databate/datatable/datagrid?

Comment: When a new row is added to a database table "Alert", the C# program creates an alert message box

Comment: You may simply add something like MessageBox.Show("Row added!") into a method, where row actually adding to your DB.

Comment: I can't! I have an arduino that reads the values and automatically passes them to the database, I have a trigger in the database that if the values pass the defined ones, it passes to the "Alerts" table, so what I have to do is when that trigger puts a row in the "Alerts" table, the C# program warns with a message box!

Comment: What is `arduino` ?

Comment: @user16034963 What are you using for the database? ADO.NET?

Comment: You can either poll the table for changes on a period that is adequate for your needs (1 minute?). You can use the Service Broker to "notify" your application of a change. Surely there are other ways as well. As you are a "trainee", this is a good question to be asking the training resources of your organization - not random strangers on the internet. If questions are discouraged or not answered at your organization, then you are not receiving "good training". Try searching for  "dashboard tutorials".

Comment: StackOverflow is not a site where users request programs and other users write them. You need to ask specific questions about what you don't understand. If you don't understand where to start, others have already mentioned that in the comments. The most simple implementation would be to poll the table every so often and show any alerts that weren't there the last time. If you don't understand specific aspects the starting point, start new questions and ask what you don't understand about them.